# Is this a Convair C-240?

Tags: aircraft-identification, convair-240-family

This aircraft is at Dodson International in Rantoul, KS. I've boiled it down to Convair. Looks most similar to a C-240. And does anyone recognize the livery?

[image]

It has USAF painted in the top of the right wing, as can be seen from satellite at 38.541248,-95.103554

Comment: Btw... one of these aircraft with rectangular windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

N43941 (USAF 53-7801) Convair C-131B.

Link to [history](http://www.aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=69292).

It saw better days:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. N-number and all. +1